# Read image behind current window

Tags: winapi, win32gui, direct2d

In Win32 or Direct2D, is it possible to read the screen that would be under the window that is being drawn? (in OnPaint() or wherever) Is it necessary to generate the screen data in back of the current window's rectangle and blit it into a memory buffer, and is this possible?

Comment: You cannot access screen content obscured by a window. You **might** be able to get the window to render itself by sending it a [`WM_PRINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145216.aspx) message, but applications are not required to properly handle it. Direct2D/3D surfaces are off limits. Little you can do.

Comment: I do not think its possible. What is your requirement? Maybe there are alternative solutions.